# Use HOC as React Component

Tags: reactjs

I've got a HOC called `withData`.

I use it as `withData(Component)`.

And need also to wrap html code in HOC in the render in the route:

```
<Route path={`/${ROUTES.HOME}`}
       render={() => (
                      <withData>
                         <Layout className="big-head" addImg>
                            <Home />
                         </Layout>
                       </withData>
                      )} />
```

By convention of HOC, its name should be in camel case (withData).
But to use HOC as component the name should be in pascal case (WithData).
Warning using camel case:

```
Warning: <withUserData /> is using incorrect casing. Use PascalCase for React components, or lowercase for HTML elements.
```

**How to avoid this error with not changing the name in the HOC?**

tried:

- const WithUserData = withUserData;
- const WithUserData = ;

got errors.

Comment: An HoC returns a new component, it's not a wrapper component that can be used as-is inside JSX directly.

Answer (score 0):

Component name should be in CAPS: WithUserData.

If you use small caps it will consider it HTML tag like `<p>, <h1>`.

Try with component name as WithUserData, it will work.